# Leaflet output is grey

Tags: r, leaflet

I would like to implement **leaflet** in **shiny** with R. I try to go with the simple examples I found online:

```
library(leaflet)
library(ggmap)

somePlace <- ggmap::geocode("Vienna")  
# Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?       address=Vienna&sensor=false  

somePlace 
#   lon      lat
# 1 16.37382 48.20817

leaflet(somePlace) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers()
```

Map shows grey space with a blue marker. No trace of OSM spatial visualisation.

[image: Leaflet Output]

Could you point out where is the problem?

Similar problems (but without a suitable solution):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31070637/r-leaflet-package-produces-blank-grey-map-ubuntu-14-04
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647872/r-leaflet-rstudio-viewer-blank-grey-map-windows-7

Edit> sessionInfo() added on request:

```
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server >= 2012 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252        LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grDevices utils     datasets  stats     graphics  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] rgdal_1.1-7          OpenStreetMap_0.3.2  osmar_1.1-7              geosphere_1.5-1      RCurl_1.95-4.8       bitops_1.0-6        
 [7] XML_3.98-1.4         mapview_1.0.0        devtools_1.10.0      ggmap_2.6.1              leaflet_1.0.1        car_2.1-2           
[13] zoo_1.7-12           dygraphs_0.8         plotly_3.4.1             dplyr_0.4.3          shinydashboard_0.5.1 shiny_0.13.2        
[19] sp_1.2-2             R2HTML_2.3.1         Hmisc_3.17-2             ggplot2_2.1.0        Formula_1.2-1        survival_2.38-3     
[25] lattice_0.20-33     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] nlme_3.1-126        pbkrtest_0.4-6      xts_0.9-7           satellite_0.2.0     RColorBrewer_1.1-2  httr_1.1.0         
 [7] tools_3.2.4         R6_2.1.2            rpart_4.1-10        DBI_0.3.1           lazyeval_0.1.10     mgcv_1.8-12        
[13] colorspace_1.2-6    nnet_7.3-12         raster_2.5-2        gridExtra_2.2.1     quantreg_5.21       SparseM_1.7        
[19] scales_0.4.0        hexbin_1.27.1       stringr_1.0.0       digest_0.6.9        foreign_0.8-66      minqa_1.2.4        
[25] R.utils_2.2.0       base64enc_0.1-3     jpeg_0.1-8          htmltools_0.3.5     lme4_1.1-11         maps_3.1.0         
[31] htmlwidgets_0.6     jsonlite_0.9.19     acepack_1.3-3.3     R.oo_1.20.0         magrittr_1.5        Matrix_1.2-4       
[37] Rcpp_0.12.4         munsell_0.4.3       proto_0.3-10        viridis_0.3.4       R.methodsS3_1.7.1   stringi_1.0-1      [43] yaml_2.1.13           MASS_7.3-45         RJSONIO_1.3-0       plyr_1.8.3          grid_3.2.4              parallel_3.2.4     
[49] rasterVis_0.37      splines_3.2.4       mapproj_1.2-4       rjson_0.2.15        gdalUtils_2.0.1.7   reshape2_1.4.1     
[55] codetools_0.2-14    stats4_3.2.4        latticeExtra_0.6-28 png_0.1-7           nloptr_1.0.4        httpuv_1.3.3       
[61] foreach_1.4.3       RgoogleMaps_1.2.0.7 MatrixModels_0.4-1  gtable_0.2.0        tidyr_0.4.1         assertthat_0.1     
[67] mime_0.4            xtable_1.8-2        rJava_0.9-8         iterators_1.0.8     memoise_1.0.0       cluster_2.0.3  R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
```

Comment: Have you checked your internet connection? The above code works just fine on my machine. See also the answer to your question on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36396612/why-does-leaflet-output-grey-map#36396806).

Comment: Cross-posted as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36396612/why-does-leaflet-output-grey-map - please do not cross-post: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4067/cross-posting-duplicate-questions-to-different-communities

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [Tour] to learn about this site and its protocols.

Comment: What is your sessionInfo()

Comment: sessionInfo added as requested @MLavoie

Answer (score 13):

I had this issue, but there was no proxy issues (I was admin, it was at home etc)
The basemap showed for me in RStudio, but not in html.

The solution is simply reminding leaflet what the basemap is. It defaults to OSM in RStudio output, but then didn't export it with html.

I simply added the tag

```
%>% addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
```

Use

```
names(providers)
```

to see all providers of basemaps.

You can also see the different basemaps at this [site](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/).

Answer (score 3):

The answer to my own question is that the local firewall settings prevented me from downloading the tiles from OSM. The way how to solve it was to set proxy (from within R > [link](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488488-Configuring-R-to-Use-an-HTTP-or-HTTPS-Proxy)). The con of this solution is that the viewer still doesn`t deliver tiles as the proxy settings at the moment do not apply to RStudio Viewer. Although, the leaflet output appears properly in browser, therefore works also with Shiny Apps. 
Thanks for the support contributing to the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record (as I pointed out above, your **leaflet** code should work just fine): you could use **mapview** (which, at least when dealing with small datasets like yours, serves as a convenient wrapper around **leaflet**) to accomplish this. Note that you are required to create a proper 'sp' object from your sample data using `coordinates` and `proj4string` prior to running `mapview`.

```
## load packages
library(sp)
library(mapview)

## setup 'SpatialPointsDataFrame'
somePlace <- ggmap::geocode("Vienna", output = "latlona")  

coordinates(somePlace) <- ~ lon + lat
proj4string(somePlace) <- "+init=epsg:4326"

## display data
mapview(somePlace)
```

[image: mapview]

Comment: Thnx for the suggestion: I get error loading mapview: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry.Seems like I need to reinstall java.

Comment: I reinstalled Java, however the package mapView loads now fine, the problem persists, the mapView(somePlace) according to your script above  return a very similar problem, a grey field and in the middle is the marker. Any further suggestion?

Comment: I think I found a hint: when I try to run the script here:http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74667/r-openproj-to-plot-in-open-street-map-in-a-different-projection
it returns an error: Could not open Bing aerials attribution metadata.
failed loading 7/71/34 tile.openstreetmap.org
...

Any idea now?

Comment: This seems to be a [known proxy issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532675/having-trouble-connecting-to-openstreetmap). Maybe you find some help [here](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/ticket/5765).